# SQL - how to get all rows that have some particular value in any one of their columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

If I have a table "FRIENDS" and it contains two attributes, user and friend, and its contents include:

(jake, kevin)

(jake, bob)

(bob, kevin)

(arnold, jake)

I want to write a query that will retrieve all of Jake's friends.  Retrieving Kevin and Bob is easy because Jake is the primary key for them.  But Arnold is also Jake's friend, except in his row, Arnold is the primary key.  How can I write a query that will, for all rows for which one of the columns is 'Jake', retrieve the *other* column?

This is for mySQL by the way.

Comment: There's no 'primary key' here

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 = 'Jake' THEN col2 ELSE col1 END AS friend
FROM tablename
WHERE 'Jake' IN (col1, col2)
```

Change `col1` and `col2` to the names of your columns.